# Add/Subtract minutes from timestamp based on arithmetic sign mentioned in another table - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table "offset_table" which have only 1 column "offset_in_minutes" (nvarchar(5)).

I will store only 1 value in offset_table.

**Example 1 :** "+300"  - This means that query should **add** 300 minutes to timestamp.

**Example 2 :** "-30"   - This means that query should **subtract** 30 minutes from timestamp.

Thus the arthimetic sign have the importance.

I want to add or subtract the minutes by taking this sign along with value from offset_table.

I have tried the following query, but is adding 300 seconds not minutes.

```
select
   start_time as original_timestamp,
   (
      start_time + (
      SELECT
         offset_in_minutes 
      from
         offset_table)
   )
   as updated_timestamp 
FROM
   students_table;
```

**Current Result:**

[image: QueryResult]

**Expected Results:**

This updated_timestamp value should be after adding 300 minutes -> '2022-10-11 06:57:52.851'

I also don't want to use (+) sign in query. This should get populated from the sign mentioned in **offset_table**.

Comment: you need to create another column in the table as operation. (+,-) in your query, you should use if else, if it is + or - according to the column you just created, you should act accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should rather use [`TIMESTAMPADD`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampadd), properly used to add parts of timestamps to timestamps in MySQL. Also, converting your `NVARCHAR` value to integer will ensure that your sum/subtraction will be automatic as long as the sign is kept during the casting operation.

```
SELECT start_time AS original_timestamp,
       TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE, 
                    CAST(offset_in_minutes AS UNSIGNED),
                    start_time) AS updated_timestamp
FROM       students_table
INNER JOIN offset_table ON 1 = 1;
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/t9NkhrnBhyx253dNEcYTFP/0).

Note: This solution assumes your offset table contains exactly one value, as specified in the problem statement.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable solution. I have changed the data type to "integer" .

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Op string
Select @Op = operation from students_table where id = 1
if(@Op == "+")
 BEGIN
  --this code
 END
ELSE
 BEGIN
  --this code
 END
```